# [Clone Linked List with next and random pointer][Runtime Error]

Tags: c, algorithm, hash, linked-list

I am trying this question using Hashing.
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/clone-a-linked-list-with-next-and-random-pointer/1

I only need to implement the function.

Here is my code.

```
struct Hash
{
    struct Node*orig;
    struct Node*copy;
};
 struct Hash H[10005];
void put(Node*k,Node*v)
{
    int idx=k->data;
    H[idx].orig=k;
    H[idx].copy=v;
}
Node* get(Node *k)
{
    int idx=k->data;
    return(H[idx].copy);
}
Node*getnode(int v)
{
    Node*newnode=NULL;
    newnode=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newnode->data=v;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    newnode->arb=NULL;
    return newnode;
}
void init_hash()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10005;i++)
    {
        H[i].orig=NULL;
        H[i].copy=NULL;
    }
}
Node * copyList(Node *head)
{
     // Your code her
     Node*curr=head;
     Node*headcopy=NULL;
     Node*tailcopy=NULL;
     init_hash();
     while(curr)
     {
         Node * newnode=getnode(curr->data);    
         if(headcopy==NULL)
         headcopy=newnode;
         put(curr,newnode);
         curr=curr->next;
     }

     curr=head;
     while(curr)
     {
         Node*copycurr=get(curr);
         //if(copycurr!=NULL)
        // copycurr->next=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
         copycurr->next=get(curr->next);
         //if(copycurr!=NULL)
         //copycurr->arb=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
         copycurr->arb=get(curr->arb);
         curr=curr->next;
     }
    return headcopy;
}
```

It is giving RunTime error.
I can think of reason.
I initialize next and random as Null and then I do

```
copycurr->next=get(curr->next);
copycurr->arb=get(curr->arb);
```

If I comment thses lines ,program runs,ofcourse wrong output.

I also tried commenting out initializing next and random as NULL but still same error.
Can anyone please suggest what error I am making.
I want to solve using my own Hash.

Edit1: Adding complete code as asked in comments:

```
        #include <bits/stdc++.h>
        using namespace std;
        struct Node
        {
        int data;
        Node* next;
        Node* arb;
        };
        Node *newNode(int data)
        {
            Node *new_node = new Node;
            new_node->data = data;
            new_node->next = NULL;
            new_node->arb=NULL;
            return new_node;
        }
        void print(Node *root)
        {
        Node *temp = root;
        while(temp!=NULL )
        {
        int k;
        if(temp->arb==NULL)k=-1;
        else k=temp->arb->data;
        cout<<temp->data<<" "<<k<<" ";
        temp=temp->next;
        }
        }
        //Node * copyList(Node *head);
        void append( Node** head_ref, Node **tail_ref, int new_data)
        {
            Node* new_node = new Node;
            new_node->data  = new_data;
            new_node->next = NULL;
            new_node->arb=NULL;
            if (*head_ref == NULL){
               *head_ref = new_node;
            }
            else
               (*tail_ref)->next = new_node;
            *tail_ref = new_node;
        }
        bool validation(Node *head,Node * res,Node *cloned_addr,Node *generated_addr)
        {
            if(generated_addr==cloned_addr)
                return false;
            Node* temp1 = head;
            Node *temp2 = res;
            int len1=0,len2=0;
            while(temp1!=NULL)
            {
                len1++;
                temp1=temp1->next;
            }
            while(temp2!=NULL)
            {
                len2++;
                temp2 = temp2->next;
            }
            /*if lengths not equal */
            if(len1!=len2)
            return false;
            temp1= head;
            temp2=res;
            while(temp1!=NULL)
            {
                if(temp1->data!=temp2->data)
                return false;
                if(temp1->arb!=NULL and temp2->arb!=NULL)
                {
                    if(temp1->arb->data!=temp2->arb->data)
                    return false;
                }else if(temp1->arb!=NULL and temp2->arb==NULL)
                    return false;
                temp1= temp1->next;
                temp2=temp2->next;
            }
            return true;
        }

        struct Hash
            {
                struct Node*orig;
                struct Node*copy;
            };
             struct Hash H[10005];
            void put(Node*k,Node*v)
            {
                int idx=k->data;
                H[idx].orig=k;
                H[idx].copy=v;
            }
            Node* get(Node *k)
            {
                int idx=k->data;
                return(H[idx].copy);
            }
            Node*getnode(int v)
            {
                Node*newnode=NULL;
                newnode=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
                newnode->data=v;
                newnode->next=NULL;
                newnode->arb=NULL;
                return newnode;
            }
            void init_hash()
            {
                for(int i=0;i<10005;i++)
                {
                    H[i].orig=NULL;
                    H[i].copy=NULL;
                }
            }
            Node * copyList(Node *head)
            {
                 // Your code her
                 Node*curr=head;
                 Node*headcopy=NULL;
                 Node*tailcopy=NULL;
                 init_hash();
                 while(curr)
                 {
                     Node * newnode=getnode(curr->data);    
                     if(headcopy==NULL)
                     headcopy=newnode;
                     put(curr,newnode);
                     curr=curr->next;
                 }

                 curr=head;
                 while(curr)
                 {
                     Node*copycurr=get(curr);
                     //if(copycurr!=NULL)
                    // copycurr->next=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
                     copycurr->next=get(curr->next);
                     //if(copycurr!=NULL)
                     //copycurr->arb=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
                     copycurr->arb=get(curr->arb);
                     curr=curr->next;
                 }
                return headcopy;
            }
        /* Driver program to test above function*/
        int main()
        {
          int T,i,n,l,k;
          Node* generated_addr=NULL;
        /*reading input stuff*/
            cin>>T;
            while(T--){
            generated_addr=NULL;
            struct Node *head = NULL,  *tail = NULL;
                cin>>n>>k;
                for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
                {
                    cin>>l;
                    append(&head, &tail, l);
                }
               for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
               int a,b;
               cin>>a>>b;
               Node *tempA=head;
               int count=-1;
               while(tempA!=NULL)
               {
                   count++;
                   if(count==a-1)
                    break;
                   tempA=tempA->next;
               }
               Node *tempB = head;
               count=-1;
               while(tempB!=NULL)
               {
                   count++;
                   if(count==b-1)
                    break;
                   tempB=tempB->next;
               }
               //when both a is greater than N
               if(a<=n)
               tempA->arb = tempB;
               }
        /*read finished*/
               generated_addr=head;
               Node *res = copyList(head);
               Node *cloned_addr = res;
               cout<<validation(head,res,cloned_addr,generated_addr)<<endl;
               }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Be wary of code found on random internet sites, geeks being one. There are good examples, and not so good examples. Now it is almost impossible to answer your question unless you edit and show us how you are putting the functions together in your code. Just looking at the functions is rather ambiguous, Please provide [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (in your question -- not a link to where more code can be found). We will then be able to compile, debug and help further.

Comment: I think your code will not work if two or more nodes have the same data :(

Comment: @David :added complete code

Comment: Thank you, but shouldn't you tag your question as C++ if you are `using namespace std;`? That's minor, and I guess you are on windows? (so you are just making use of `<iostream>` (e.g. `cin` and `cout`) instead of using `stdio.h` functions? Doable, but a bit odd.

Comment: `136:14: warning: unused variable ‘tailcopy'` and `80:17: warning: declaration of ‘i’ shadows a previous local`, from `165:11: int T,i,n,l,k;` You should always compile with warnings enable and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. (minimum warnings `-Wall -Wextra` (and really you should add `-pedantic -Wshadow`) for gcc/clang and `/W3` for VS (`cl.exe`)) That will save you much debugging. I haven't determined if those are related issues, but that is where you start.

Comment: Look at `copyList` function what happens if your list has 1 element ? You call `get(curr->next)` but this is NULL and in your `get` function you don't handle this case, you try to read data `int idx=k->data;` and you got segmentation fault.

Comment: As @rafix07 pointed out, the primary problem with your code is failing to check for `NULL` in `get`, simply adding `if (!k) return NULL;` resolves the problem. Your code will then run without memory error returning `true` with each call to `validation`. (though you fail to `free` the data you allocate and since you fail to preserve a pointer to the beginning of each block -- you can't). You need to remove the *shadow* declaration of `i` by removing `int` from `for(int i=0;i<k;i++)` at about line 180.